# CAN transceiver interconnection to MCU (Tx, Rx and propagation delay)

Tags: microcontroller, can, delay, transceiver, propagation

I am working on a CAN transceiver and its connection to a microcontroller (hardware perspective only.)

Referring this appnote - [What is CAN?](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_156%20What%20is%20CAN.pdf)

My questions:

[image]

1. In the above image, I see the CAN transceiver connections to the MCU. I have seen UART communications where Tx is connected to Rx and vice vera for proper transmission of data, but there seems to be an exception with the CAN communication protocol. Why is Tx connected to Tx and Rx connected to Rx? Can someone help me to understand why is this exception?
   Are there exceptions like this for any other protocol?
2. In both the microcontroller and the transceiver, Tx is connected to Tx and Rx is connected to Rx. How should I understand this? From the diagram, thevRXD pin from the transceiver transmits the data to microcontroller and the TXD pin of the transceiver receives from the microcontroller. Is my understandng correct? From which perspective should we understand the transmit and receive parameters? Should the Tx and Rx parameters always be from the microcontroller point of view?
3. I am using this transceiver IC - [TLE7263E](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Infineon%20PDFs/TLE%207263E.pdf)

[image]

I can understand the dominant and recessive states on the CAN bus, but I am not able to understand the above table of propagation delays.

I tried to correlate the table with the Fig.20 CAN dynamic characteristices timing diagram on page 56 but it is not clear to me.

Can someone help me to understand each parameter of the propagation delay table and Fig.20?

Comment: Propagation delays are internal delays of path design how long it lasts a signal propagating to the output and I think you can ignore this actual for your application.

Comment: Typically CAN it is not named after functions like UART but after Affiliation.

Comment: OK sure. In what scenario would I need to consider these parameters while design? But also, I would like to understand the parameter definitions for my understanding. I searched online, but couldn't find them or relate those definitions to the datasheets and my understanding. Could you please write an answer for my questions?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why pick such a specialized exotic transceiver? It appears to be for CAN/LIN gateways specifically, with tons of extra fluff... and since it's Infineon it will be great quality but cost a fortune, have extreme lead time and no 2nd source.

Comment: This IC has integrated Voltage regulators also

Comment: @Newbie And it can probably brew coffee too :) If internal regulator is the only reason, I'd pick some other part. Getting a cheap switch regulator up & running isn't rocket science these days, you could just grab a reference design from your favourite silicon vendor.

Comment: No no. I am not using only for regulator alone. It has 2 Regulators and CAN and LIN interface as well. Yes sure. It does cost. Will look for other parts as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Tx connected to Tx and Rx connected to Rx.

Luckily, CAN did not repeat the mistakes of UART.

For UART communication, you need to consider if a node is a "modem" or a "terminal", that is if it's in the middle of the bus or at the end of it. Pairing Tx from one terminal with Rx of the other terminal and so on. As everyone who have worked with UART knows, Murphy's law applies with 100% accuracy: you *always* get Rx and Tx wrong, no matter how much planning you do. It's like a curse - the UART signal system was simply not a good idea.

There's no such thing as "modem vs terminal" in CAN. The actual signal on CANH/CANL is semi-duplex on the same wire. Tx/Rx in CAN is just a local affair between the controller and the transceiver.

> In Both MCU and Transceiver, Tx is connected to Tx and Rx is connected to Rx. So how to understand this?

There's not much to understand, your picture is great, it shows exactly how it works. Tx and Rx are just signal names, named after the CAN controller (MCU) side of things.

> But I am not able to understand the above table of propagation delays

I'm not the right person to explain all the dirty details of this, but as mentioned in comments, one probably doesn't need to know. As with any data communication, you have a propagation delay along the whole bus including circuits, but is most likely negligible in most CAN applications, unless you have extreme real-time specs (nanosecond accuracy). 
CAN bit clocking uses a "propagation segment" with built-in tolerance for these delays.

What's far more important to consider is your CAN controller clock source. This should be a fairly high quality one with at least 1.5% accuracy. Quartz oscillators are strongly recommended, particularly for the higher baudrates.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Are there any other protocols where the TX and RX pairing are similar to CAN ?

Comment: @Newbie RS-485 for example, it is is quite similar to CAN with semi-duplex differential signals.

Answer (score 0):

It's checking if the signal that it sends is the same as the one getting received; because on a CAN BUS, during the arbitration process, if the identifier of one node sends a 0 and another sends a 1, the node that sent a 0 will receive a 0, while the node that sent a 1 will also receive a 0. This means the node that sent a 1 will stop sending, wait for the bus to go quiet, and probably try sending the message again; however, the one that sent a 0 will continue sending, and if it is the end of the arbitration, it owns the bus until its message is sent. This also means that only one message can be sent at a time on the CAN BUS, and the message being sent depends on the id of the message being sent.

When there are two nodes sending at the same time, that both have the same identifier but different message values - it can cause a specific HWI to occur on the controlling hardware, to notify of data loss and which node identifier is responsible, or it can just do nothing and just accept the mangled data which might be a 0 or 1 depending on how the processor interprets the non-logical value.

Timings only need to be worried about for off-nominal (i.e. really long) BUS lengths, or noisy environments. Remember that all nodes have to be timed to the slowest transmitting node. Default timing values will work for nearly any device that meets ISO requirements, on a 'standard' CAN BUS. The parameters just explain the limits on how far the controlling hardware can adjust the timing parameters, for a custom BUS.

These are also some of the reasons for why CAN is such a robust communications protocol, and still growing in popularity.

Here is the link to the processor datasheet that was used during my embedded systems research at UH; refer to section 17 for a detailed description of CAN BUS operation:
"https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf"